# 1D vector - 3D indices

Tags: c++, arrays

I am using a 1D vector to represent a 3D data structure, with indices 0 to x*y*z, where x, y and z are the number of cells in each direction.

In order to index a specific cell [xi][yi][zi], I use:

```
index = xi + x*yi + x*y*zi ;
```

My problem is, I can't work out how to go the other way!

e.g. I want to get the individual coordinates represented in index 43.

I think I've worked out how to get xi:

```
xi = index % x ;
```

but I can't for the life of me get the others... :/

EDIT: Hmmm. Is this right?

```
xi = index % x;
yi = ((index - xi)/x) % y;
zi = ((index - xi - x*yi) / x) / y ;
```

Comment: Your edit is right, but the subtractions are unnecessary because of the integer division

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
xi =   index % x;
yi =  (index / x) % y;
zi = ((index / x) / y) % z;
```

This can be easily generalized as one might expect.

Comment: The `%z` is unnecessary, but it does clearly show how to generalize this.  Heaven forbid someone need 4, 5 or 6 dimensional arrays though!

Comment: I heard that "they" use ~7 dimensional arrays in chess programs, so who knows ;) I find the `% z` not bad because it allows for automatic cyclic array indexing, which can come in handy.

Comment: I'm not sure I approve of cyclic array indexing, most of the time (for me at least) if my index is larger than my array that's an error but the cycling would hide that.  Although in other circumstances if it's handy, then it's handy and I would approve.

Answer (score 1):

Some modular arithmetic should do the trick.

```
    index % x = (xi + x*yi + x*y*zi) % x = xi % x,
    but 0 <= xi < x therefore xi % x = xi.
```

Then for yi:

```
    (index / x) % y = yi.
```

Then lastly:

```
    index / (x * y) = zi.
```

**EDIT:**

In code (as opposed to math above) it would be:

```
    xi = index % x;
    yi = (index / x) % y;
    zi = index / (x * y);
```

Comment: good answer... since this is a coding site, maybe at least make the last equations look like something that could be code? (I've never seen an assignment operator like that)

Comment: @Shep you're right, I just enjoy math questions so much I forget the little details.  Edited the answer